# Is there a way to retrieve a value from an object contained in an array property of google dataLayer via GTM

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, javascript-objects, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I created a dataLayer variable in GTM and for some reason I am getting undefined for that variable although the data was pushed to the dataLayer (I could see the values in Chrome DevTools console).

Note: I am able to get the property values of all objects and child objects but not the value of an object which is an array item (see below example).

`var data = {
        id: 123,
        name: 'Joe',
        actions: [
            {
                type: 'some type',
                desciption: 'Some description'
            }

        ]
    }`

With the above data is pushed to the dataLayer, I'm able to access id and name with below in GTM

```
data.id
data.name
```

However, when I try to access type from actions property with below **Data Layer Variable Name** I get undefined.

```
data.actions[0].type
```

Is there something I'm doing wrongly or what is the correct way to access the value of type in GTM using Data Layer Variable Name (Version 2). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When accessing array indexes within the GTM interface for variables etc., you need to use a custom GTM notation which is basically dot notation for arrays. Just replace brackets for a "." before the index of the array.

Your code in the question would become:

```
data.actions.0.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable "debug" in GTM? If so, enable that and then load the page and open Developer Tools and see what variable is populated with the data you want and work backwards from there.

I'm not sure the exact Javascript terminology for what I'm about to describe but in the `data` array(?) or object(?) `id` and `name` are immediate descendants/children.

But then when you get down to `actions` you have an extra set of brackets between the `actions` and the `type` or `description`.

Maybe that doesn't matter, JS really isn't my thing but if you enable debug in GTM then you can open up Dev Tools and see the exact syntax of the variable/object that contains the data you want and copy/paste it into your code.

Answer (score 0):

`window.dataLayer` is Javascript Array, not sure how you push the object to the dataLayer, but if do in below way.

```
window.dataLayer.push({
        id: 123,
        name: 'Joe',
        actions: [
            {
                type: 'some type',
                desciption: 'Some description'
            }

        ]
    });
```

Then you can access the `actions` by doing this way.
This is just simply checking if the first `action` exist, then getting the action array.

```
window.dataLayer.find(_ => _.actions).actions[0].type
```